# Tiny motherboard with full functionality?

Tags: motherboard, mini-pc

I need to fit a fully-functioning mobo with an LGA1151 cpu socket and a PCI-E x16 slot for my gpu and at least 2 RAM slots in a 11 x 5.5 x 7 case. It also has to have a maximum RAM capacity of at least 32GB. No need for fancy stuff like LED controllers or anything though. Just the bare functional basics, because it will be in a very closed off case, so it doesn't need to look nice at all. Does anyone know of a 1: Very small but full-featured motherboard, or 2: a company that would be willing to manufacture 1-2 motherboards of a very small size for a couple hundred dollars. Any other options would also help, but those are the main 2 things I'd be looking for. My budget per board is around $250, give or take a bit.

EDIT: I've read around a bit, and I've figured out that it will probably be way too much money to make a mobo, but what about modding an already made one?

Comment: I've heard that it's very expensive to manufacture even one mobo:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate your dimensions into normal terms, you're looking for a Mini-ITX (or Mini-DTX) board.

I'd recommend the [Asus H110I-PLUS/CSM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813132717&ignorebbr=1), $86 from Newegg:

- 6.7" x 6.7"
- Socket LGA1151
- Two RAM slots supporting a total of 32 GB
- One PCIe 3.0 x16 slot
- Reasonably "full-featured": 4 SATA ports, 6 USB ports, Ethernet, eight-channel audio

The chipset and voltage regulators are passively cooled with small heatsinks, which may or may not be a problem for a "very closed off case".

I don't have any experience with this particular product, but I've had good luck with Asus mainboards in the past.

Here is a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_form_factor) to form factor sizes for reference.  This can provide you all the options for size options that are offered based on size standards.  Keep in mind that anything smaller than Mini-ITX is unlikely to have a PCIe slot, and is likely to have just a single SO-DIMM slot for memory.

Comment: Also, isn't mini ATX smaller than mini-ITX?

Comment: @WillHopkins, there are two "mini-ATX" form factors: 5.9" x 5.9", and 11.2" x 8.2".  They're both rare -- Amazon lists one board that uses the 11x8 standard, and neither Amazon nor Newegg lists a board that uses the smaller standard.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why when I look up mini-ATX i just get ATX and min-ITX in the search results:)

Comment: Also, is there a board with an LGA1150 socket that you'd recommend? I found some that I'm looking into, but they don't have the best reviews... It's a $60 one from MSI... it should be fine tho cuz this is a test PC and not the final build. I'll be using my 1151 i7 in the final one and a 1070 FE, but for this i'm using an i5 with the lga1150 and a 960 SSC...

Comment: It's unlikely there will be an LGA1150 board that meets your requirements.  Most LGA1150 CPUs only support 8 GB per memory stick, and Mini-ITX boards almost never have more than two memory slots.